# Poor adhesion on new layer - Monoprice mini select

Tags: troubleshooting, adhesion, monoprice-select-mini

On my Monoprice Mini Select v2 there is poor adhesion when the print head goes to put down a new layer on the bed as seen in the photo. Does anyone have a fix for this?

[image]

Comment: What is your first layer print speed? It seems to me like you're printing too fast and the filament hasn't enough time to settle on the bed.

Comment: I print super slow for the whole print since it seems like I get better detail this way

Answer (score 1):

You could try a higher bed temp, but also check to make sure bed is levelled all round as this can sometimes cause this to happen

Comment: I’m pretty sure the bed is leveled but I’ll check it again. Would another surface like painters tape, or a glass bed upgrade help?

Comment: I find printing on glass bed with tape always gives a  better result but the build tech material is just as good it just needs regular cleaning after each print as oil from your fingers can get onto it and it rests on the top, looking at your image it seems to stick fine after that first bit, painters tape is OK but doesn't always work I use https://www.wanhaouk.com/products/wanhao-print-bed-tape

Answer (score 1):

If you have already used alcohol to eliminate grease and fingerprints, sometimes scrubbing the print surface with a regular green scotchbrite pad can restore adhesion. It micro-scratches the surface and seriously increases the surface area of contact.

This all assumes you have properly calibrated the bed, reduced first layer print speed by at least 50%, increased first layer print thickness By >= 50%...

Answer (score 0):

Things you need to check or do:

1. Use adhesion layers
2. Set lower speeds at first layer.
3. Increase bed temperature (try 5 degrees steps)
4. Clean the bed
5. Check if the bed is completely leveled up.
6. Increase the thickness of the first layer.